# How to determine velocity of two objects after they collide?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

Let's say an object of mass 1 kg is moving 10 m/s. A second object of mass $m_2$ is at rest. When the two objects collide, they stick together and move 8 m/s. what is $m_2$?

I understand how to solve this problem using the Law of Conservation of Momentum:

$m_1v_1$ = $(m_1 + m_2)v_2$ so 1(10) = (1 + $m_2$)(8)

Therefore, $m_2$ = 0.25 kg

---

However, I don't understand why I can't use the energy approach to solve this problem.

$KE_1$ = $KE_s$ (KE of first object = KE of two objects after collision)

$(1/2) * 1 * 10^2 = (1/2) * (1 + m_2) * 8^2$

Therefore, $m_2$ = 0.5625 kg, which is incorrect

Why isn't it correct to use the energy approach in this problem?

Comment: Energy isn't conserved in [inelastic collisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inelastic_collision#Perfectly_inelastic_collision).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conservation of momentum but not kinetic energy in inelastic collisions](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133759/conservation-of-momentum-but-not-kinetic-energy-in-inelastic-collisions)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is there no relation between kinetic energy and momentum in collision of two bodies?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/145589/why-is-there-no-relation-between-kinetic-energy-and-momentum-in-collision-of-two)

Answer (score 0):

If the objects collide non-elastic , a part of the total energy transforms into inner energy (usually deformation energy and thus temperature), which lowers the kinetic energy of the new object.