# If momentum and kinetic energy are related, how loss in energy doesn't cause loss in momentum?

Tags: energy, kinematics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

Kinetic energy and momentum are related to each other by the following equation:
$$K.E.=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\textbf{P}^2}{m} $$
In inelastic collisions the momentum is conserved but the energy isn't. How can this be correct in the view of previous equation?

Moreover, if I want to rewrite the previous equation in term of change of momentum and change of kinetic energy, is the following true or not?

$$\Delta K.E.=\frac{1}{2}\frac{(\Delta\textbf{P})^2}{m} $$

If that is wrong, what is the true form?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92051/how-can-momentum-but-not-energy-be-conserved-in-an-inelastic-collision?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa Possible duplicate

Comment: @Turbotanten I already saw this question but all answers didn't address this direct relation between momentum and kinetic energy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity's sake, let's restrict ourselves to collisions in 1 dimension, where object 1 collides with object 2. They have momenta $p_1$ and $p_2$ before collision and $p_1'$ and $p_2'$ after collision. We then have
$$\begin{align}
p_1' + p_2' &= p_1 + p_2,\tag{1}\\
K' = \frac{p_1'^2}{2m_1} + \frac{p_2'^2}{2m_2} &= \frac{p_1^2}{2m_1} + \frac{p_2^2}{2m_2} + \Delta K = K + \Delta K,\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
where $\Delta K = K' -K$ is the change in kinetic energy. Note that Eq. (1) by itself does not have a unique solution: only the total momentum is conserved, not the individual momenta. Each solution $(p_1',p_2')$ will correspond with a different value $\Delta K$, and there will be only 1 specific solution for which the collision is elastic, i.e. $\Delta K=0$.

It is instructive to write the solutions in terms of the so-called [coefficient of restitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution)
$$
C_R = \frac{v_2' - v_1'}{v_1 - v_2} = \frac{m_1p_2' - m_2p_1'}{m_2p_1 - m_1p_2}.\tag{3}
$$
Evidently, $v_1 > v_2$, otherwise there would be no collision. Also, $v_2' > v_1'$, because object 1 cannot get passed object 2. So $C_R\geqslant 0$. The value $C_R = 0$ corresponds with a *perfectly inelastic* collision, where both objects stick together after they collide.

Using Eq. (1) we find
$$\begin{align}
1 + C_R &= \frac{m_1(p_2'-p_2) + m_2(p_1-p_1')}{m_2p_1 - m_1p_2}\\
&=\frac{(m_1+m_2)(p_1-p_1')}{m_2p_1 - m_1p_2}\\
&=\frac{(m_1+m_2)(p_2'-p_2)}{m_2p_1 - m_1p_2},
\end{align}
$$
so that the possible solutions are of the form
$$\begin{align}
p_1' &= p_1 - (1 + C_R)\frac{m_2p_1 - m_1p_2}{m_1+m_2},\\
p_2' &= p_2 + (1 + C_R)\frac{m_2p_1 - m_1p_2}{m_1+m_2}.
\end{align}
$$
Next we derive the relation between $C_R$ and $\Delta K$. First, note that
$$\begin{align}
2m_1m_2(m_1 + m_2)K &= (m_1+m_2)(m_2p_1^2 + m_1p_2^2)\\
 &= m_1m_2(p_1 + p_2)^2 + (m_2p_1 - m_1p_2)^2,
\end{align}
$$
and
$$\begin{align}
2m_1m_2(m_1 + m_2)K' &= m_1m_2(p_1' + p_2')^2 + (m_1p_2' - m_2p_1')^2\\
&=m_1m_2(p_1 + p_2)^2 + (m_1p_2' - m_2p_1')^2,
\end{align}
$$
so that
$$
2m_1m_2(m_1 + m_2)\Delta K = (m_1p_2' - m_2p_1')^2 - (m_2p_1 - m_1p_2)^2.
$$
We plug this into Eq. (3), and obtain
$$\begin{align}
C_R &=\sqrt{1+\frac{2m_1m_2(m_1 + m_2)}{(m_2p_1 - m_1p_2)^2}\Delta K},
\end{align}
$$
or alternatively,
$$
\Delta K = (C_R^2 - 1)\frac{(m_2p_1 - m_1p_2)^2}{2m_1m_2(m_1 + m_2)}.
$$
Since $\Delta K\leqslant 0$, we get $0\leqslant C_R\leqslant 1$. For *elastic* collisions, $\Delta K = 0$ and $C_R= 1$.

To summarize, for each value of $C_R$ between $0$ and $1$ we get a possible solution, each corresponding with a different value of $\Delta K$.

Answer (score 0):

The momentum of one system is  conserved *if no force acts on it*.

Your problem is that you look at one system alone, and when force acts on it, you think that momentum isn't conserved.

If for example a clay ball A of mass $m$ and velocity $v$ collides with an identical ball B moving at opposite direction. They both stop by symmetry.

If you look at system A alone, it's KE went from $\frac{mv^2}{2}$ to $0$, and so did its momentum. But that's to be expected since an outside force acts on it.

Look at systems A and B together. Momentum is *vector*, so the total momentum of the systems  A, B together is 0. since KE is *scalar*, their total $KE = mv^2$. When the 2 balls collide, the momentum is unchanged and the KE decreases to 0.